# Implement Windows calculator layout with JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

How to implement Windows calculator with `JPanel` in Java?

I want to implement windows 7 calculator in java, I am newbie in implement GUI in java,
please tell me how can I implement  calculator GUI with `JPanel` in Java.

[image]

I think first use **BorderLayout()** to frame, and add **textfield** to **north** then put label in **center** and in **South** using  jpanel with girdLayout(4*1) ,
really I completely confused

Would appreciate any help:

Comment: Have you tried what you thought of? Didn't it work? What did it look like?

Comment: See the [Nested Layout Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) for ideas about how to *combine* layouts to create the required layout.

Answer (score 1):

I see a main `JPanel` and 6 subordinate `JPanel`s.

The first subordinate `JPanel` is the display.  It would have a `FlowLayout` with one `JLabel` for the number display.

The next `JPanel` is the binary number display.  It would have a `GridLayout` with 32 `JLabel` fields.

The next 2 `JPanel`s hold the `JRadioButton` groups.  They would have a `FlowLayout`, and the radio buttons would be in `ButtonGroup`s.

The next `JPanel` consists of the first 3 columns of buttons.  It would have a `GridLayout` with 18 `JButton`s.

The final subordinate `JPanel` consists of the last 5 columns of buttons.  It would have a `GridBagLayout`, because of the zero and equals buttons.

The main `JPanel` would have a `GridBagLayout`.

Put this GUI together, by hand (no GUI builder) one `JPanel` at a time.  I would have a separate class for each subordinate `JPanel`, and another class for the main `JPanel`.  Seven classes just for the `JPanel`s.

Comment: can you explain "Put this GUI together, by hand (no GUI builder) one JPanel at a time. I would have a separate class for each subordinate JPanel, and another class for the main JPanel. Seven classes just for the JPanels."  more, tnx

Comment: @zhilevan:  Construct the display panel.  See that it works.  Construct the number keys panel.  See that it works.  Rinse and repeat for the remaining 4 subordinate panels.  When the subordinate panels are completed, then try to put the entire calculator together.  Each subordinate panel should be in its own Java class.  Each subordinate panel should have a GUI model class that contains the data for the subordinate panel.